# Nagios verify Sharepoint

Tags: linux, sharepoint, nagios

I want to set Nagios (on my Debian) to verify a SharePoint server is up. I already tried to use `cURL` but it didn't worked for some issue that I don't know so I decided to change the way I'll verify that service.

It's simple in theory, I just have to make a script to send an request (http or https, doesn't matter) and check the response, if is 200 for successful or 40x if not (ok at this point).

So I have to use `telnet` or any ftp service to do that or I can use another feature/tool for that.

With telnet I'am having problem with 400 error. SharePoint returns this error when server is up or down, so I don't work for me.

Any ideas??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I done my own way to check if SharePoint is UP or DOWN. Please pay attention that this script just checks the service status, nothing more like user permissions or whatever.

Perl script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use LWP::UserAgent;
use Getopt::Long qw(:config no_ignore_case_always auto_version);

GetOptions ('h=s' => \my $h);

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
$ua->agent('Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.0; Windows 95)');

my $req = $ua->get('http://' . $h);

my $retorno = '';

if ($req->is_success) 
{
    $retorno = $req->content;
}
else
{
    $retorno = $req->status_line;
}

if ($retorno eq "401 Unauthorized")
{ 
    print "OK: SharePoint service at " . $h . " server is UP.";
    exit 0;
}
else
{
    print "CRITICAL: SharePoint service at " . $h . " server is DOWN.";
    exit 2;
}
```

In case you got this exception when you run the script:

> Can't locate LWP/UserAgent.pm in @INC

this article may help you as it helped me:

http://help.directadmin.com/item.php?id=274

So in Nagios `commands.cfg` file you'll declare the command this way:

`command_line /usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_sharepoint.pl -h $HOSTADDRESS$`

Where `$HOSTADDRESS` is the host IP variable in Nagios scope.

Remember to `chmod +x` on the file. I know you will...

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [check_http](http://nagiosplugins.org/man/check_http) plugin of Nagios. For example:

```
check_http -H SharepointHostname/IP -p port
```

- You can use the -S flag for secure http connections
- You can use the -u flag for going to specific URL
- You can use the -s flag to search for a specific string in the HTML page returned from the url specified with the -u flag.

So basically you can request a specific page, scan for a known String, and if successfully found, you are sure this page is up (which means server is up etc.)

Example:

```
check_http -H my.sharepoint.com -u /start/page/sharepoint.aspx -s "test string"
```

Commonly this is done on login pages etc. Don't forget to escape special chars in your URL, if it contains any (like ? and &).

There's also a [perl script](http://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Plugins/Email-and-Groupware/Microsoft-Sharepoint/check_sharepoint-2Epl/details) available for checking sharepoint servers.

Answer (score 1):

Does this not do what you want:

http://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Plugins/Email-and-Groupware/Microsoft-Sharepoint/check_sharepoint-2Epl/details

Most likely you're going to need a login/password for Sharepoint in order to monitor much more than the basic IIS / website is working.